# Different Sales Tax for different locations of same country in Magento

Tags: magento, state, country, city, sales-tax

Hi I need to set the tax rule in Magento by following the below conditions.
 All purchases shipped to California, but outside of San Diego, are charged the same rate, which is 7.25%.
 All purchases shipped to San Diego (part of the state of California) are charged the rates enclosed in the spreadsheet.
 Most of the rates are 7.75%, but some are different.

1. Examples (All purchases shipped to California, but outside of San Diego)
   product1 $24.95
   Shipping & Handling $4.95
   Sub Total $29.90
   Sales Tax (7.25%) $2.17
   Total $32.07
2. Examples - All purchases shipped to San Diego (part of the state of California) Shipped to Coronado, California
   product1 $24.95
   Shipping & Handling $4.95
   Sub Total $29.90
   Sales Tax (7.75%) $2.32
   Total $32.22
3. Examples - All purchases shipped to outside of the state of California
   product1 $24.95
   Shipping & Handling $4.95
   Sub Total $29.90
   Sales Tax (0%) $0
   Total $29.90

Shall I need to make 3 different Rules for above 3 cases in Magento administrators panel under
Sales->Tax->Manage Tax Zone Rates  or defining only one rule is enough?

Comment: not a programming question :(

Comment: hey :) no need to bitter about it. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) section of this site. You can also help moderate the forum and keep it in tracks of solving programming issues. If you find that something is too general then you can down-vote it and explain why you down-voted it. I have also made such mistakes and answered bogus topics that were later closed down. I know that for you it is easier to ask your question wherever you like but such freedom often leads to chaos in terms of finding programming answers from stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a lots of RnD,finally I solved the issue.we need to make 3 different Rules for above 3 cases in Magento administrators panel under Sales->Tax->Manage Tax Zone Rates.
then we need to mention all the 3 in Sales->Tax->Manage Tax Rules .